# How to get diagonal numbers between two number in a matrix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

How to check if two indexes of a square matrix are diagonal to each other. Consider the array.

```
[
 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ,
 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 ,
 8 , 9 , 10, 11,
 12, 13, 14, 15
]
```

Create a function which takes three parameters array and two indexes. It should return a `true` if two indexes are diagonal to each other otherwise return `false` For above array.

```
0,15 => true
3,12 => true
11,6 => true
9,6  => true

4,15 => false
8,12 => false
1,10 => false //my code fails for this.
```

I have tried to create a function but it doesnot work at all.

```
function check(arr,a,b){
  let len = Math.sqrt(arr.length);
  let dif = Math.abs(a-b);
  return dif % (len+1) === 0 ||  dif % (len - 1) === 0
}
```

Can some give a simple solution to it.

Comment: what is `arr`? ..

Comment: What's happening here: `Math.sqrt(arr)`

Comment: @appleapple `arr` is the array that is getting passed.

Comment: @adiga `arr` will always be a 1D array whose length will be a perfect square. It means its just like square matrix.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt well then `Math.sqrt(arr)` make no sense.

Comment: @R3tep There can be any number of lines just that a square matrix meaning the length of the array will always be a square of an integer

Comment: @appleapple Its actually `.length`. I missed that.

Comment: @MaheerAli Please let me know from where you are getting these problems, even I want to give it a try

Comment: Why is `11,6` -> `true`?

Comment: Because 11 is on a diagonal to 6 @adiga.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I am not getting this problem from anywhere. I just need it for my chess game.

Comment: @JackBashford I might be misunderstanding it .Isn't `1` diagonally opposite to `11`?

Comment: Yes but 6 lies along a diagonal to 11.

Comment: @R3tep It fails for `1,10`

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt If you want programming problems go to **project euler**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simply get the col and row, and check if delta is the same.

(don't really need to take an array, so I just take it's dimension)

```js
function check(dim,a,b){
  let [x1,y1]=[Math.floor(a/dim),a%dim]
  let [x2,y2]=[Math.floor(b/dim),b%dim]
  return Math.abs(x1-x2)==Math.abs(y1-y2)
}

console.log(check(4,0,15))
console.log(check(4,3,12))
console.log(check(4,11,6))
console.log(check(4,9,6))
console.log(check(4,4,15))
console.log(check(4,8,12))
console.log(check(4,6,12))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could take the absolute delta and check with the remainder operator if the delta is multiple of the length minus one or plus one.

```js
function check(array, i, j) {
   var length = Math.sqrt(array.length),
       delta = Math.abs(i - j),
       lines = Math.abs(Math.floor(i / length) - Math.floor(j / length));
   
   return delta === lines * (length - 1) || delta === lines * (length + 1);
}

var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

console.log(check(array, 0, 15)); // true
console.log(check(array, 3, 12)); // true
console.log(check(array, 11, 6)); // true
console.log(check(array, 9, 6)); // true

console.log(check(array, 4, 15)); // false
console.log(check(array, 8, 12)); // false
console.log(check(array, 8, 3)); // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this fails for (3,8)

Comment: yes I think it's correct now. one point, though. `!(delta % minus) && delta === lines * minus` is effectively the same as `delta === lines * minus` (and same for plus)

Comment: and you are doing `1%0` if dimension is 1, although the result would still be correct.